# Perl Tcl::pTk read Tcl version

Tags: perl, tcl, tk-toolkit

I want to use Perl to read in the version of Tcl version that the module 
[`Tcl::pTk`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tcl::pTk)
is linked to. I found the following which is working fine

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Tcl::pTk;

my $int = new Tcl::pTk;

$int->Eval(<<'EOS');
# pure-tcl code to create widgets (e.g. generated by some GUI builder)
text .e
## http://wiki.tcl.tk/1626#tk_version
.e insert end "tcl_version      $tcl_version\n"
.e insert end "tcl_patchLevel   $tcl_patchLevel\n"
.e insert end "tk_version       $tk_version\n"
.e insert end "tk_patchLevel    $tk_patchLevel\n"
.e insert end "tk_library       $tk_library\n"
pack .e
EOS

my $e = $int->widget('.e');     # get .e entry into play
$int->MainLoop;
```

This displays the value in the GUI but I want to use `$tcl_version` in other parts of my script. In this I fail, as `$tcl_version` seems not to exist. I do not need the GUI part, just the values of the scalars.

Comment: Tcl::pTk itself isn't really "linked" or tied to a specific Tcl/Tk version since it's pure Perl. It's the Tcl.pm library (which Tcl::pTk uses) that can be compiled to use a specific Tcl/Tk version. The accepted answer here is a good way to check at runtime which version is being used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest thing that could possibly work should be tried:

```
my tcl_version = $int->Eval('info tclversion');
```

Alternatively and equivalently on the Tcl side:

```
my tcl_version = $int->Eval('set tcl_version');
```

All Tcl commands produce a result, so that ought to be reflected across here. Also, most of the time you are better off getting the patch-level for version reporting; the language version is just really for gross features, not anything detailed like system state reporting (e.g., you need the patch number for bug reports).

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Comment: Consider accepting the answer, if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've since found undocumented methods in Tcl::pTk, `$int->tclVersion` and `$int->tclPatchlevel`, which are equivalent to `$int->Eval('info tclversion')` and `$int->Eval('info patchlevel')` respectively.

They were already used internally in Tcl::pTk. I do not plan on removing these, but also do not know if it is a good idea to keep them in the long term or make them "public"/documented, so it may be better to stick with the existing answer's approach. (Tcl::Tk, which Tcl::pTk is based on, does not have these methods.)